# why am i getting a javascript reference error?

Tags: javascript, php, html

here is the code. i've made a function in javascript in a PHP file.

```
  function getGeneratedLink(){
 alert("hi");
    $('#generateLinkModal').show();
    $('.generated_link_section').slideDown("fast");
    $('.generated_link_section').show();
$("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body span.message").hide();
$("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body input").hide();
$("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body span.loader-gif").show();

$.ajax({
    type:       "POST",
    url:        <?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/generateLink') ?>,
    data:       {},
    async:      false,
    dataType:   "json",
    success:    function(data) {
                    $("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body span.loader-gif").hide();
                    if (!data['session']) {
                        $('.generated_link_section').slideUp('fast', function(){
                            alert(data['session_msg']);
                            window.location = data['url'];
                        });
                    } else if (!data['success']) {
                        $("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body span.message").text(data['error_msg']);
                        $("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body span.message").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body input").val(data['link']);
                        $("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body input").show();
                    }
                }
});

 }
```

Later on i am making call to this function, like this, not included html tags

```
onclick="getGeneratedLink()">New Registration Link</button></a></li>
```

it shows reference error, function is well included between script tags.

i have tried few variants of function calling.. with no fruitful results..

i dont know, what is causing this error

```
     <pre><code>
 <div class='admin-work-area'>
        <!-- Jquery files -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $baseURL ?>/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $baseURL ?>/jquery/jquery-blockUI.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $baseURL ?>/jquery/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
            <!--BOOTSTRAP-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>/bstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>/bstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!--CUSTOM STYLESHEET-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $baseURL ?>/wizshark/css/style.css" media="all" />

    <ul id="admin-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle='tab' href="#tab-manage-users">Manage Users</a></li>
        <?php if($isSuperAdmin) { ?>
        <li><a data-toggle='tab' href="#tab-manage-admins">Manage Admins</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <li><a data-toggle='tab' href="#tab-alogs">Audit Logs</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle='tab' href="#tab-charts">Monitor Charts</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" style="min-width: 100px;max-height: 20px"><input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query nopadding-verticle"></a></li>
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><button class="btn nopadding-verticle" onclick="getGeneratedLink()"><i class="icon-plus"></i> New Registration Link</button></a></li>
                    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><button class="btn nopadding-verticle" onclick="javascript:void window.open('<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/addNewUser') ?>','1359116962684','width=800,height=650,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');return false;"><i class="icon-plus"></i> New User</button></a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="admin-tabs-content" class="tab-content admin-tabs-content">

        <div id="tab-manage-users" class="tab-pane active">
            <ul class="unstyled list list-users">
                <li>
                    <div class="headers">
                        <div class='username'> &nbsp; <b> Username </b> </div>
                        <div class='email'> <b> Email </b> </div>
                        <div class='status'> <b> Status </b> </div>
                        <!--<div class='usage'> <b> Usage </b> </div>-->
                        <div class='count-quota'> <b> Traces / Quota </b> </div>
                        <div class='upload-size-quota'> <b> Size / Quota </b> </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!-- the list of divs of users will come here-->
            </ul>
            <span id="list-users-json" style="visibility:hidden">
                <?php echo $admin_model->get_users_list(); ?>
            </span>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                display_users();
            </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: whether the function `getGeneratedLink` is within another function like a dom ready handler

Comment: nope it is a separate function..actually it is only function in script tag.

Comment: any other errors in your browser console

Comment: nope// other buttons are working just fine, other buttons are calling other javascript function..
.. if i call only alert on this button then it works fine.
but cant make a call to javascript fnct from this button

Comment: @Himanshu97 Works fine _[here](http://jsfiddle.net/93WMP/1/)_ .Just make sure your `jquery` library comes before this.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger jqery files are included..

Comment: @Himanshu97 Could you please paste the full code with where you are including the library and where the function is being called?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger
ADDED CODE IN QUESTION.. FROM WHERE I AM CALLING

Comment: create a *minimal* example. pick *one tag*. show some effort.

Comment: @Himanshu97 If you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/EPMKE/1/ This does not work but the exact same here: http://jsfiddle.net/EPMKE/2/ works because the `<script>` tags are placed inside the `<head>` section. I am not sure why is that so but try shifting your script tags either under `<head>` or at the end of your code.

Comment: actually this page doesnt have a head and body.. its consisting of div only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php echo $this->createUrl('admin/generateLink') ?>` is going to generate an url without any quotes around it. JavaScript string literals must have quotes around them.

Use `<?php echo json_encode($this->createUrl('admin/generateLink')); ?>` instead.

When you have a JavaScript error, always examine your actual JavaScript and not your PHP.

Comment: javascript is being used when other fncnts from it are being called..i dont see a problem there